# bash - for loop through multiple directories and their files

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, nested, cdo-climate

I have 5 directories in the same path `my_path/`:

```
my_path/1951 
my_path/1952 
my_path/1953 
my_path/1954 
my_path/1955
```

Each directory contains a different number of netcdf files ending in `.nc`.

And I need to perform a `CDO` command by looping in each directory and files. The command below applies only to the first directory and files `my_path/1951/*.nc`:

```
for i in my_path/1951/*.nc
do
   cdo selyear,1951/1970 "$i" "$i"2
done
```

The command select years from the nc files in the directory starting from the year of the directory and ending 20 years later.

So for the second directory it will be:

```
for i in my_path/1952/*.nc
do
   cdo selyear,1952/1971 "$i" "$i"2
done
```

and for the third:

```
for i in my_path/1953/*.nc
do
   cdo selyear,1953/1972 "$i" "$i"2
done
```

etc...

Is there a way I can do everything with a unique for loop or nested for loop instead of repeating the for loop above for each directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in my_path/*/; do
    year=${i%/}; year=${year##*/}       # extract year
    year2=$(( year + 19 ))              # add 19
    for j in "$i"*.nc; do
        echo cdo "selyear,${year}/${year2}" "$j" "$j"2
    done
done
```

It outputs command lines as a dry run. If it looks good, drop `echo` and run.

Comment: wow a bash for loop looking estetically nice

Comment: @aaaaa: Opinion-based. I much prefer the `do` on a line of its own, like you did in your question. And having multiple statements in one line is generally frowned upon, regardless the language. ;-)

Comment: definitely. de gustibus non est disputandum :P

Comment: @DevSolar thank you for the comment. I may be affected by K&R C coding style which puts the left curly brace in the same line. The benefit is I can see more lines in the screen IMHO. As for the assignments of `year`, I just wanted to save the comment. Apart from them, I do agree with your opinion.

Comment: @tshiono: I came a bit late for K&R and went right for C++ (and Stroustrup's ANSI style). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in my_path/195[1-5]/*.nc
do
  ...
done
```

The `shopt` command ensures that the loop works even if some of the directories don't contain a nc file.

Comment: thanks. but what is inside the loop changes too with the given directory, or is not the same command for all directories.

Comment: I know, but you are calculating now already (i.e. in the attempt you have posted) `year` and `year2`. Since you oviously know how to take apart a variable, I assume that you can do a similar calculation for the new loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
for x in $@
 for i in my_path/$x/*.nc
  ...
```

you can do On2 for with getting parameters of sh script.

```
yourScript.sh 1951 1952 ...
```

After that you can pass all folder to your script.

```
yourScript.sh ./*
```

Comment: This does not address the fact that the parameter after the comma has to change for each directory.